# Using Lockbits to search for black pixels, but does this randomly?

Tags: c#, gdi+, ocr

I got a problem with Lockbits. I'm searching black pixels, and because it does not seem right, I'm using a WindowPopup to print the colors of every pixel, but it's like my program is using another picture.

[alt text http://i208.photobucket.com/albums/bb91/Savaronna/pixel-1.jpg?t=1234874238](http://i208.photobucket.com/albums/bb91/Savaronna/pixel-1.jpg?t=1234874238)

I marked the first found black pixel red. As you can see there are several other pixels that should match too. What am I doing wrong?

This is my script, do I oversee something?

```
Bitmap b = this.TableListBMP;
BitmapData bmpData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),
                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
                                PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

int stride = bmpData.Stride;
IntPtr Scan0 = bmpData.Scan0;

unsafe
{
  byte * p = (byte *)(void *)Scan0;  
  int nOffset = bmpData.Stride - b.Width*4;    
  int xOffset, yOffset;

  for(int y=5; y<b.Height; ++y)
  {
    for(int x=1; x<b.Width; ++x)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(
        string.Format("x={0}, y={1}, ARGB={2},{3},{4},{5}",
          x, y,
          Convert.ToString(p[(y*stride)+(x*4)]),
          Convert.ToString(p[(y*stride)+(x*4)+1]),
          Convert.ToString(p[(y*stride)+(x*4)+2]),
          Convert.ToString(p[(y*stride)+(x*4)+3])));
      p +=4;
    }
    // EDIT: This line should be removed
    p += nOffset;
  }
}
b.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using offsets such as `p[((y)*stride)+((x)*4)]`,  you probably shouldn't be increasing p at all? Surely you've already handled that (`x` and `y`) with the multiplication? Also, `bmpData.Stride - b.Width*4` is not (as far as I can see) a meaningful number... the stride is the rows size including padding.

Either remove the "`p += ...`" code, or change the offset algorithm. At the moment you are skipping data (bad) and accessing data outside of the object (**very** bad).

Comment: just want to let you know, I deleted the p += part and it works.

Thanks for your help